# Trying to pass sudo password directly through STDIN

Tags: c, pipe, sudo, file-handling

This is my program, and it doesn't seem to be working. Sometimes I thought it worked with `\0` or `\r` instead of `\n`, but I guess that is because I had already executed a sudo command on the terminal where I ran this program, so it didn't prompt me for password.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE* pipe = popen("sudo -S ls", "w");   
   pwrite(pipe,"mypass\n");
   pclose(pipe);
   return 0;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `sudo` tests whether it's running on a TTY and will refuse to work if not.

Comment: You could find out if the current process is being run as root, and if not prompt for the _user_ to use `sudo` instead of this.

Comment: Thanks @KerrekSB and Nick, for giving some pointers. Really appreciate it. Managed to find a workaround, answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out a workaround that seems to be working. Thanks everyone, who looked into the question.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   FILE* pipe = popen("echo mypass | sudo -S ls", "w");   
   pclose(pipe);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is better achieved by modifying sudo configuration so it doesn't ask for a password.